# Separate TAG when there is comma

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make that when I type ***tag, tag, tag*** inside input[type=text] and click/press **ADD** button the result will be 3 tags. And avoid ***duplicate tag***.

```
<div class="upload-input-tag clearfix">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Tags">
    <button type="button" class="btn add-tag">ADD</button>
    <span>Separate tags with commas</span>
</div>
<!-- content for added tag -->
<div class="upload-added-tag">
    <div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>hiphop</div>
    <div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>bezells</div>
    <div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>streets</div>
    <div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>dream</div>
    <div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>visuals</div>
    <div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>sauce</div>
</div>
```

> **JQUERY**

```
$(".add-tag").click(function(){
  var newTag = $.trim( $('.upload-input-tag input').val() );

  if (!newTag) return; //avoid adding empty div
    var newAddedTag = '<div class="added-tag"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>' + newTag +'</div>';   

    $(".upload-added-tag").append(newAddedTag);

    $(".upload-input-tag input").val(''); //clearing value

    $('.remove-tag').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  });
```

The adding and removing tag is working fine, what I want to add to jQuery is to detect that if I used comma(,) inside input it will separate and if avoid duplicate tags but I'm not that good enough to make it work. I'm still learning JS/jQuery :D

> **THANK YOU FOR HELPING!**

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking for multiple keycodes (you might want to make tags when they hit enter or tab or some other key).

```
$('input[name="tag"]').on('keyup', function(e){
    var breakKeys = [9, 188, 13]; //add less or more codes from http://keycode.info/
    if(breakKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0 && $(this).val() !== ''){
        makeTag($(this).val())
    }
})
```

Depending on the key you chose, you might need to remove it from the value you pass into the next function (like comma). Just use `String.slice()` for those.

From here, just have a new function that makes a tag. You can also check existing tags inside of that function, but I recommend wrapping the tag text in an element for easy reference.

```
function makeTag(value){
    var html = '<button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button><span>' + value +'</span></div>';
    var existing = $('.upload-added-tag .added-tag span').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).get();
    if(existing.indexOf(value) < 0){
         $('<div/>').addClass('.added-tag').html(html).appendTo('.uploaded-added-tag');

    }
}
```

The `existing` variable might look weird, but it's super helpful when you want to make an array of values that are kept within jQuery objects.

Comment: I like the idea of keycode but the code that you provide is not working I have mine with the enter(9) only but when I tried to add more it's not working `$('.upload-input-tag input').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
    $('.add-tag').click();
    return false;  
  }
});`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a split on the `,` character. That will create an array of text objects. Then you can iterate through those objects and create an element for each. To avoid duplicate tags, use a counter to add an attribute to each element.

```
$(".add-tag").click(function(){
  var newTag = $.trim( $('.upload-input-tag input').val() );
  if (!newTag) return; //avoid adding empty div
  var tags = newTag.split(','); //CREATE AN ARRAY BASED ON COMMA PLACEMENT
  for (var i in tags) { 
    //THE USE OF  id="tag-' + i + '" WILL PREVENT DUPLICATE TAGS
    var newAddedTag = '<div class="added-tag" id="tag-' + i + '"><button type="button" class="remove-tag btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></button>' + tag[i] +'</div>'; 
    $(".upload-added-tag").append(newAddedTag);
  }
  $(".upload-input-tag input").val(''); //clearing value
  $('.remove-tag').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: There was an error on line of the "var newAddedTag" that says this

custom.js:128 Uncaught ReferenceError: tag is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:128)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)